# Is, beta reduction in type theory being considered as counit for hom-tensor adjunction in category theory, a denotational or operational semantic?

Tags: type-theory, category-theory

In [the article at nlab about the relation between type theory and category theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relation+between+type+theory+and+category+theory), it is said that "beta reduction" in type theory corresponds to "counit for hom-tensor adjunction" in category theory and also "substitution" corresponds to "composition of classifying morphisms / pullback of display maps" correspondingly.

Are these considered denotational or operational semantics?